# Calling an asynchronous method in WCF from PHP

Tags: c#, php, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm not sure if you get my question but I am currently working on making my methods in my WCF project asynchronous.

I read that it's possible to call an async WCF method from C# (client side) like

```
await WCFAsyncMethod;
```

I haven't done anything like it in PHP.

Comment: whats the question? are you asking if you can use c# keywords like await in PHP, because pretty sure t that's a no. They may have something similar

Comment: how can I make an asynchronous call to my web service from PHP?

Comment: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2005/may/guru-multiplexing/

Comment: thanks @sa_ddam213 looks like what I just needed. appreciate it a lot!